# The syntax of the method

Tags: java, loops, methods

Want to find out the point of describing method in parentheses that way, unknown "v" variable and interesting form of loop.

```
public static double findMax(double...values)
   {
       double largest = Double.MIN_VALUE;

       for(double v : values)
           if(v > largest)
               largest = v;
       return largest;
   }
```

Comment: Read about the enhanced for loop and varargs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(double...values)` means the method takes one or more parameters. You can call the method with different number of parameters. They are threated as an array.

```
findMax(23.0, 13.0);  // values array contains 2 double value
findMax(12.0,13.0,17.0) // values array contains 3 double value
```

`for(double v : values)` means the for loop iterates on every element in `values` array. On every iteration the next element in `values` array assigned to `v` variable.

Answer (score 0):

1 - double ... values means that there is at least 1 double or more double parameters that method can take.

2 - For loop can be used like that similar to foreach loop.